# Does YOLO rescale anchors before fully connected layers? What is the solution for the absence of ROI pooling?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I read dozens of articles about YOLO but didn't find this answer. The question is: Faster R-CNN uses ROI Pooling to rescale anchors before the fully connected layers, but YOLO doesn't. Some people say YOLO doesn't need ROI pooling because it doesn't have RPN, but **YOLO does have different anchors with different sizes/proportions**, each one trying to detect an object. How can a neural network be trained with this anchors with different sizes? 
Yolo calculates a confidence score and a class score, but I can't understand how it's possible without reshaping the anchors.

Answer (score 1):

You speak from fully connected layers and anchor boxes in yolo. Only the first version of Yolo had a fully connected layer but no anchors. Yolo v2 and v3 are both full CNNs without any fully connected layers, but with anchors.

In the first yolo the width and height were directly predicted relative to the width and height of the input. In Yolov2 and v3 anchor boxes were used and only a rescaling of the anchors width and height is learned in the same manner as in e.g. Faster R-CNN, SSD.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. If I got it right, YOLO tries to learn by looking directly at the feature map. For instance: some specific activations at some location can indicates a dog, so if an anchor has it's activations inside, this anchor will likely receive a high confidence score. Is it right?

Comment: I believe you are mixing up RPN + ROI pooling and anchor box approach from Yolov2. An anchor is just some default box with a given width and height. Yolov2 divides the input into a regular grid and in every grid cell N anchors are placed. The network then predicts for every grid cell for every anchor the regression parameters and the class probabilities. There is no ROI pooling, so there is nothing like looking at specific activation in feature map like you described.

Comment: Ok, but what are these class probabilities for an anchor based on? I mean: the algorithm receives some input and then calculates the probabilities. What is this input? I think this input is the neurons located inside the anchor. Is it right?

Comment: The input is the image and the network predicts the probabilities. I don't know what you mean with "inside the anchor". The anchor is part of the detection layer and acts basically as a bias, so the network has to predict only some offsets. The anchors itself are not part of the network like the weights are. Maybe read the yolo9000 or SSD paper again to get a better idea of what is happening.